# Shader Storage Buffer Object element reading optimization

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl, shader-storage-buffer

Im doing trillinear interpolation using Shader Storage Buffer Object.
So i access my ssbo in fragment shader like this:

`layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer ColorSSBO { int value[]; };`

```
int c000 = value[x0 + y0 * dataWidth + z0 * area];
int c100 = value[x1 + y0 * dataWidth + z0 * area];
int c010 = value[x0 + y1 * dataWidth + z0 * area];
int c110 = value[x1 + y1 * dataWidth + z0 * area];
int c001 = value[x0 + y0 * dataWidth + z1 * area];
int c101 = value[x1 + y0 * dataWidth + z1 * area];
int c011 = value[x0 + y1 * dataWidth + z1 * area];
int c111 = value[x1 + y1 * dataWidth + z1 * area];
```

It is becoming very inefficient since this buffer is huge, if I could read multiple elements of the array at once it would be great, or at least those that go in a row

I dont need to modify this array, I feel like I missing something, maybe there is some keyword for readonly

this is how I load ssbo using lwjgl:

```
public void loadSSBO(int[][] values){
    if (ssbo != 0) GL15.glDeleteBuffers(ssbo);
    
    int size = values[0].length;
    long pixelSIZE = size * (Integer.SIZE / 8);
    
    ssbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL33.glBindBuffer(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, pixelSIZE * values.length, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);   // declare buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        GL15.glBufferSubData(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, pixelSIZE * i, values[i]);
    }
    GL33.glBindBufferBase(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssbo);
    GL33.glBindBuffer(GL43.GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);    //unbind
}
```

Comment: "*if I could read multiple elements of the array at once it would be great, or at least those that go in a row*" The data cache is already doing that.

Comment: @NicolBolas oh, okay. I was thinking that if I could read multiple values at once it would be equivalent in performance to reading just one element

Comment: " feel like I missing something, maybe there is some keyword for readonly" Yes, it is called [`readonly`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object#Memory_qualifiers) but I don't think using it will make any difference. But are you sure you can't use 3D textures forn your use case? Fitst of all, the data locality is improved even when you use integer texture and manual filtering. Don't know about your scenarion, but maybe you could use floats instead and use the texture unit to do the filtering.

Comment: @derhass hi, thanks for answer, I am not familiar with 3d textures, could you give me something to get started with?

Comment: Well, are your familiar with 2D textures? It is the same thing, just in 3 dimensions. Your `x0 + y0 * dataWidth + z0 * area` access pattern looks a lot like this is just a 3D array, something which you couldput into a 3D texture.  But I have no idea of what your data represents and your use case is, whether  `x0` and `x1` are always neighboring cells, and wether integer data format is a strict necessity.

Comment: @derhass yes they're always neighbours, integer is not necessery, I'd rather use short if there was possibility, I can convert it to float if there is a need

Comment: Well, in that case, a 3D texture with `GL_R16` or format would be ideal. it's a normalized integer format that maps the `[0,65535]` range to the `[0,1]` float range on access, but that wont' make a difference for the filtering, and if you need the unsigened short range back, you just can multiply it. Uf you need signed shorts, `GL_R16_SNORM` will do the similar thing (just with mapping to the [-1,1]` range).

Comment: @derhass thank you, maybe I will try it